# django: blog() missing 1 required positional argument: 'blog_id'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, blogs

I am attempting to add a blog to an existing test website, but I am receiving the following error message:

```
blog() missing 1 required positional argument: 'blog_id'
```

This may be a simple mistake I have made, but I am stumped at what I have done incorrectly and how to fix this. I have searched google and SO, but I haven't found a suitable reference.

Here is my models class:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=150, unique=True)
    blog_description = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=500)
    blog_script = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=5000)
    blog_date_released = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    blog_tags = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=150)
    blog_video_url = models.URLField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=250)
    blog_timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    blog_timestamp_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from myapp.core.decorators import *
from myapp.core.models import Blog

def blog(request, blog_id):
    blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_id)
    ....
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', {
        'blog': blog,
        'display_default_language': the_display_default_language,
        'language_versions': language_versions,
        'language_versions_num_enabled': language_versions_num_enabled,
        'language_versions_num_total': language_versions_num_total,
        'var_page_title': _("Blog"),
    })
```

Here is mu urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url(r'^blog/blog/$', views.blog, name='blog'),
]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show your `urls.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `blog_id` from your urls:

```
from . import views

url(r'^blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$',views.blog, name='blogs'),
```

Comment: @user1261774, Have you tried?? did it worked for you?

Comment: Thank you. I have put your code in to my code. I now have the following error message: `Reverse for 'blog' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<blog_id>\\d+)/$']`. Any suggestions.

Comment: Should I use singular blog (typo?): `url(r'^blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$',views.blog, name='blog'),`

Comment: This problem is with your `html` file where you are giving link for blogs. post your html file.